# Gazebo world, strange behavior on collision. Robot gets thrown away

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu

I recently build a gazebo world to simulate a garden. It has a house, greenhouse, kids playground and others. I used Blender to build the world and picked models from 3D Warehouse.

So far so good. But when I drive my robot around and it collids with objects, robot gets thrown away in an insane way. It gets catapulted around even if the obstacle is just 1cm height.

In my opinion, this gets caused by my world as when I place my robot in Turtlebot3 world, it doesn't act like this. Here it just stops at the walls with turning wheels.

I defined a body inertia of 8kg mass and a wheel inertia of 1kg mass. The caster wheel is defined as a sphere with nearly no friction. The entire world consists of just one model. This is defined as static.

[Here a video showing this behavior compared to Turtlebot3 world](https://youtu.be/G-KF2L3ZmSo)

And [here a link to my repo containing the world](https://github.com/HoverMower/hovermower/blob/humble/hovermower_simulation/worlds/garden_world.world) and models as well a[s the robot URDF file itself](https://github.com/HoverMower/hovermower/blob/humble/hovermower_description/urdf/hovermower.urdf)

It would be great if someone could explain why the robot acts like this in my own world.

BR Patrick